# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (String Chopper)

Tags: exception, nullpointerexception

I have the following class:

```
public class{
  public static String[] guillotine(String[] s){
    String[]inArray = new String[3];
    String[]outArray = new String[inArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < inArray.length; i++)
      outArray[i] = inArray[i].substring(1);
    return outArray;
  }

  public static void main(String[]args) {
    String[]a = {"meat", "fat", "flukes"};
    String[]b = guillotine(a);
    System.out.println(b);      
  }
}
```

I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException |at class.guillotine(Jacknigger.java:8) |at class.main(Jacknigger.java:13)`

Comment: So, which is line 8?  Whatever it is, there is a reference (pointer) being used in that line that is null.  You need to use a debugger or println statements to figure out which reference is null, and then figure out why.  NullPointerException is one of the easiest of all Java errors to debug, so it's a good one to practice on.

Comment: outArray[i] = inArray[i].substring(1);

Comment: ive never debugged, i use eclipse, how would one go about this?

Comment: yes, its just a placeholder

Comment: There are many Eclipse debugging tutorials available at the end of a Google search. You are not going to get very far in programming without knowing how to do this.

Comment: Use println statements.  I've been programming Java almost since it was born, and that's all I ever use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NPE is likely on this line: `outArray[i] = inArray[i].substring(1)` - though you've created `inArray`, you haven't initialized any of its members to anything, so `inArray[i]` is null.

Based on the fact that you're completely ignoring `s`, the input to that method, you probably want to replace

```
String[]inArray = new String[3];
```

with

```
String[]inArray = s;
```

so it'll actually use the array you're passing in.